# Trying to make a function that when you input a string of numbers it returns true if the length of the numbers is 4 or 6 and they are all numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

```html
def validate_pin(pin):
    if (len(pin) == 4 or 6) and pin.isalnum == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It works for some but numbers like "1234" are returned as "false" even though it should be True

Comment: This won't work:  `len(pin) == 4 or 6`  It's equivalent to `(len(pin) == 4) or 6)` which is always true.    Instead do `len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6`, or more concisely `len(pin) in (4, 6)`.

Answer (score 3):

You have some syntax errors:

- you need to provide the left hand side operator for each comparison in your `if` statement
- `isalnum` is a function, so it needs to be called. You were checking whether the function itself is type `bool` of value `True`, which evaluates to false since the function `isalnum` is a built in method.

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    if (len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6) and pin.isalnum() == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Note that you don't need to have `== True` in the `isalnum()` comparison, since the function already returns a boolean object:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    if (len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6) and pin.isalnum():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I would describe them as bugs rather than syntax errors. The code in the question is valid syntax, despite clearly not doing what is intended.

Comment: Or more concisely, `return (len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6) and pin.isalnum()`

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

`len(pin) == 4 or 6`

this is evaluated as `(len(pin) == 4) or (6 is truthy)`. All numbers other than 0 are truthy, so that second half is a problem. This should instead be
`len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6`

`pin.isalnum`

pin.isalnum is a function, aka a bunch of instructions that the computer understands, and a bunch of instructions is never equal to `True`.  You have to actually tell python to call (execute) the function to see if the instructions return true or false. You call a function by putting parentheses after it:

```
>>> "123".isalnum()
True
>>> "123".isalnum
<built-in method isalnum of str object at 0x108064ce0>
>>>
```

Also, you don't need to check if it's equal to true - pin.isalnum() will be evaluated, and then whatever the answer is, it gets put in that place. So you can just say `... and pin.isalnum()`, no need to check if the result is true or not.

Putting it together, your statement should be

```
if (len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6) and pin.isalnum():
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use regex something like `^\d{6}$|^\d{4}$`
or this `^\d{4}(\d{2})?$`

https://regex101.com/r/AFksCd/1

Comment: So if you use this with `re.match`, it will match anything that starts with at least 5 digits (e.g. `'12345'` or `'12345foo'`). It would not match `'1234'`.

Comment: Yeah, I goofed up - regex is still IMO the right answer, you should've edited the answer - s/o doesn't need to be a place where we spoon feed solutions I could've easily answered "use regex" and that would've been a valid answer..

Comment: I dispute that the onus was on me to edit it, but now that you've corrected it yourself I am happy to change the downvote to an upvote.